# for...of loop not working when remote debugger is disabled

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

When the debugger is disabled, I get this error:

`undefined is not a function (evaluating '_iterator[typeof Symbol === 'function' Symbol.iterator:'@@iterator']()')`

But when it is enabled, my code works fine. This only happens on android. The ios app works fine.

Here are my dependencies:

- react
- react-native
- native-base
- base-64
- realm

And here is the code that makes the difference:

```
for(toy of toys) {
   console.log(toy)
}
```

If I uncomment the line above, my code works without the debugger.

Comment: Not an expert at all on the topic but, could it be a possibility that with the debugger disabled `console` is not defined?

Comment: Content of toys? is Toys is an array or an object? Plain objects are not iterable

Comment: An array of objects. @EnieJakiro

Comment: @JordiNebot Not really, since it's working with iOS.

Comment: Have you changed any babel configuration? or imported a package that conflicts with babel

Comment: @EnieJakiro, I haven't. I did not even touch babel configuration. All of my packages are the ones listed above. I don't find anything related to the ones listed and their conflict with babel.

Comment: I recommend switching to another loop for now - and maybe try on other android versions and devices

Comment: @EnieJakiro, yeah thanks. I'm using recursive function as an alternative. But I still hope this can be answered. I found a similar post about this in github but it was because of a dependency called 'css-react-native' or something like that. But I'm not using it so that might not be the solution in my case.

Comment: same here, had to rewrite to for index loop

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but based on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterables)
you can only use a `for ... of ...` loop on a iterable object. That is, the object must implements the `@@iterator` interface.

For some reason it seems that when debugging the running JS interpreter behaves different (maybe because when debugging the SDK uses a different one).

EDIT: It seems that there are issues with Symbol and the @@iterator in React Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5294#issuecomment-190061913

Originally this issue was present in Android and iOS 8.x, but was fixed for iOS 9 (that explains why your code works there). Android version seems to have still some issues.

Comment: Arrays are iterable objects, and he can iterate through an array of objects with `for .. of ..`

Comment: @EnieJakiro An object is iterable if `obj[Symbol.iterator]` is a function, and the error message clearly states that it is undefined, which is not a function

Comment: Hi @Pablo, this works well with iOS with or without the debugger. I can even access toys[index] so my array of objects is not the problem.

Comment: @Pablo, I checked my babel.rc, nothing unusual in there.